# when I use the repr function it is not working

Tags: python, repr

I am trying to remove the ' ' in my list by using the repr function but it is not removing the ' '

code:
output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrhvj.png)

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8Nnk.png)

Comment: Please include code and errors as text and not as images.

Comment: The '' means that the elements in your list are strings.   Change each element as an int.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The quotes mean that those are strings, not integers.  If you want them to be integers, you have to convert them:

```
mylist = list(map(int,mylist))
```

I would also point out that `repr` is not intended to be final output.  It's used for debugging and intermediate results.  If you need a specific format, then YOU need to build the specific format you want.